# type object 'datetime.timezone' has no attribute 'now'

Tags: python, django, timezone

This line of code is receiving an AttributeError:
`now = timezone.now()`

I can't figure out why. I am correctly importing the package as follows:
`from django.utils import timezone`

But it is still throwing:

`Attribute Error: type object 'datetime.timezone' has no attribute 'now'`

Model

```
class Donaci(models.Model):
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)

    def whenpublished(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        
        diff = now - self.creation_date

        if diff.days == 0 and diff.seconds >= 0 and diff.seconds < 60:
            seconds= diff.seconds
            
            if seconds == 1:
                return str(seconds) +  "second ago"
            
            else:
                return str(seconds) + " seconds ago"
```

Imports

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth import settings
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models
from datetime import *
```

Comment: You likely also imported `timezone` from `datetype`.

Comment: Please show the full traceback and the relevant parts of the file.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, I also have ``from datetime import *``

Comment: You shouldn't really import `*` as it leads to this exact issue. Change your datetime to import only what you're using.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import *
```

first imports `timezone` from `django.utils` but then this gets overridden by your * import from Python's datetime module which also has [`timezone`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#available-types) (and many other things).

When you do `timezone.now()`, it's using Python's `datetime` `timezone` object instead of `django.utils` `timezone` object, which is why you see the error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.timezone' has no attribute 'now'
```

If you had imported the other way around:

```
from datetime import *
from django.utils import timezone
```

`timezone.now()` would work because the `timezone` object would be overridden by `django.utils` `timezone` object.

**Advice**: don't do star imports unless you know it won't conflict.

Answer (score -2):

Use this:

```
import datetime
```

instead of this:

```
from datetime import *
```